# Angular: scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code taken from the ng-book:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <h1>Hello {{ clock.now }}!</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function MyController($scope) {
        var updateClock = function() {
            $scope.clock.now = new Date();
        };
        setInterval(function() {
            $scope.$apply(updateClock);
        }, 1000);
        updateClock();
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I solved it doing this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <h1>Hello {{ clock }}!</h1>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function MyController($scope) {
        var updateClock = function() {
            $scope.clock = {'now': new Date()};
        };
        setInterval(function() {
            $scope.$apply(updateClock);
        }, 1000);
        updateClock();
    };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is why wasn't the first code not working?

UPDATE: Updated the second code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with `$scope.clock.now = new Date();` you're trying to set a property `now`to an undefined object (`clock`). with `$scope.clock = {'now': new Date()};` you set `clock` to be an object and then assign the property. a verbose way is:

```
$scope.clock = {}; 
$scope.clock.now = 'value';
```

Comment: ah I see, well the explanation still applies. i'll adapt it

Answer (score 1):

Because there was no 'now' property on the clock object in the first example

Comment: no worries, you've changed your question now though, so my answer looks stupid :)

Comment: It is still valid. It answers why.. The other answers are just more 'complete' :)

Answer (score 1):

the now() method of Date is a static method, so you could say this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1>Hello {{ clock.now() }}!</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MyController($scope) {
    var updateClock = function() {
        $scope.clock = Date;
    };
```

and it will give you milliseconds, if you really want to call the now method of the date object.

Comment: I suspect `{{ clock.now() }}` will lead to a max digest iterations error. Angular finishes its digest cycle when no `$watch` expression (`{{}}` is a hidden `$watch`) gives a different value compared to the previous digest iteration. Since `clock.now()` will give a different value every time it is checked, digest with not complete (10 iterations max -> error).

Comment: That is a good observation.  It didn't have any problem when I threw it together and tried it in Firefox, but ymmv.  I don't think it is a solution for what he is trying to do anyway, just a note on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The first code isn't working because there is no **$scope.clock** defined (Angular raises an error: **TypeError: Cannot set property 'now' of undefined**)

So this

```
$scope.clock.now = new Date();
```

should be this:

```
$scope.clock = {};
$scope.clock.now = new Date();
```

or like you solved it:

```
$scope.clock = {now: new Date()}
```